# How to execute parent lifecycle hook before child one in a Vue application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

We've got the following parent component (`App.vue`)

```
<template>
  <b-container
    id="app"
    fluid
    class="px-0"
  >
    <b-row no-gutters>
      <side-bar :routes="routes"/>
      <b-col>
        <notifications position='top center' />
        <user-info :routes="routes"/>
        <b-row no-gutters class="router-view">
          <b-col>
              <router-view/>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
import UserInfo from './views/navbar/UserInfo'
import SideBar from './views/sidebar/SideBar'
import AuthService from '@/services/auth.service'
import NotificationsService from '@/services/notifications.service'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { UserInfo, SideBar },
  data () {
    return {
      routes: [
        { name: 'app.dashboard', params: {}, icon: 'home', text: 'Dashboard' },
        { name: 'app.jobs', params: {}, icon: 'briefcase', text: 'Jobs' },
        { name: 'app.firms', params: {}, icon: 'th-large', text: 'Firms' }
        // { name: '#', params: {}, icon: 'user', text: 'People' },
        // { name: '#', params: {}, icon: 'gavel', text: 'Bids' },
        // { name: '#', params: {}, icon: 'users', text: 'MF People' },
        // { name: '#', params: {}, icon: 'chart-bar', text: 'Reports' }
      ]
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.loginOnLoad()
  },
  methods: {
    async loginOnLoad () {
      this.authService = new AuthService()
      let user = this.authService.sso()
      if (!user) {
        this.loginFailed = true
        await this.login()
        await this.authService.assignAccessTokenToHeader()
        NotificationsService.successNotification('Logged in successfully')
      } else {
        await this.authService.assignAccessTokenToHeader()
        NotificationsService.successNotification('Welcome Back')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

`assignAccessTokenToHeader` dispatches a Vuex action which assigns the result of the authenticated user in the store

This is the child component (`Dashboard.vue`)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row class="border-bottom" no-gutters>
      <b-col sm="12" class="px-4 py-3">
        <h3 class="text-uppercase">Dashboard</h3>
        <h5 class="font-weight-normal text-secondary mb-0">Personalised Favourites</h5>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row no-gutters>
      <b-col>

        <b-row no-gutters>
          <b-col sm="6">
            <b-card title="Firms" class=""></b-card>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>

        <b-row no-gutters>
          <b-col sm="6">
            <b-card title="Firms" class=""></b-card>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>

        <b-row no-gutters>
          <b-col>
            <b-card title="Firms" class=""></b-card>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>

        <b-row no-gutters>
          <b-col>
            <b-card title="Firms" class=""></b-card>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
<!--        <b-card title="Bids" class="d-inline-flex w-25">-->

<!--        </b-card>-->
<!--        <b-card title="Jobs" class="d-inline-flex w-50">-->

<!--        </b-card>-->
<!--        <b-card title="People" class="d-inline-flex w-50">-->

<!--        </b-card>-->
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AppService from '@/services/app.service'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  created () {
    this.loadGridAndContent(this.userDetails.psref)
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      userDetails: state => state.auth.user
    })
  },
  methods: {
    async loadGridAndContent (psRef) {
      let data = await AppService.loadDashboard(psRef)
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

`Dashboard.vue` is rendered inside the `router-view` of `App.vue` and the route is `/`

Now, we would like `App.vue`'s created hook to always be ran first but it looks like `Dashboard.vue` tries to run its created hook before the `App.vue` one and hence fails because it uses `psref` which is acquired in the parent.

What would be a work around that or a correct way to implement so that user login information is always acquired first, stored in the Vuex and then child components can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, whenever your child component runs a **mounted()**, that is dependent on a parents action or mounted lifecycle hook, you can avoid it loading beforehand by putting a **v-if** on your **child component**. As soon as your parent has finished its task, you simply toggle a variable to **true** and then your child gets loaded, so you avoid empty or null values.

Comment: the thing is we are using the `created` hook in both components and not the `mounted` one. According to this article https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f the parent `created` hook gets executed before the child one. Since we are storing the user data through the parent should it not be available for the child after we use `...mapState` in it?

Comment: It runs beforehand, but because it's `Async` it doesn't mean it will finish before the Child runs its `created` hook.

Comment: There's a whole discussion on this topic https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7209 . Someone is suggesting that `async created()` works, but I haven't tried this and I'm not sure an application should be structured like this.

Comment: Interesting discussion, we actually have some `async created()` which works fine after unit testing but in this case it doesn't work. We tried the `v-if` solution you suggested by storing a login boolean after the parent has finished its work and then mapping this boolean in the child and using it but again the child hooks seem to run before the parent has ended